# Calculating the enthalpy of formation for ethane in Gaussian

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-chemistry

I am attempting to run a benchmarking calculation in Gaussian software to obtain the enthalpy of formation for a series of molecules. I am using the example calculation found  [here](https://gaussian.com/wp-content/uploads/dl/thermo.pdf) for ethane (C2H6). The author utilizes non-optimized structures at the HF/STO-3G level of theory. I have attempted the same calculation, however, at the B3LYP/6-31G* level of theory. I have calculated individual electronic energies for both C and H using this method as well as for ethane, whose structure has been optimized. To find the enthalpy of formation at $0$ K, the author uses this equation:

$$\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ = 2\Delta_\mathrm{f,exp}H_{\ce{C}}^\circ + 6\Delta_\mathrm{f,exp}H_{\ce{H}}^\circ - 627.5095\times(2\mathcal{E}_{0,\ce{C}} + 6\mathcal{E}_{0,\ce{H}} -(\mathcal{E}_{0,\text{eth}} + \mathcal{E}_{\text{ZPE,eth}}))$$

The first terms in the expression are obtained experimental values for the heat of formation regarding the individual atoms of C and H. The term 627.5095 is used to convert from Ha to kcal/mol. The next terms pertain to the total electronic energy for the individual elements, not including the ZPE which is $0$ for these. Finally, we have the electronic energy and the ZPE for the ethane molecule, obtained from a frequency calculation. Following this work, I have obtained for ethane, at $0$ K, a heat of formation of -223 kJ/mol, which seems wildly different than the experimental value of -68 kJ/mol.

Does anyone have any tips on how to accurately calculate thermochemical values using Gaussian? I am using the example given by the company, but following the work there appears to be yielding inaccurate values. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Much too tired to think about it properly but have you mixed up your units? You talk about kcal earlier in and kJ at the end, and there is very roughly a factor of 4 difference between what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Are you obtaining the same values in Ha for the individual terms shown in Table 1 ?

Comment: I cannot check the whitepaper right now, but if the author comes close with the HF level of theory, which is more like educated guessing, you should come close with B3LYP, too. Can you post the values you have used, please.

Comment: @IanBush Oh I so wish that were the case! I have double checked these pretty thoroughly however.

Comment: @BuckThorn So, using the same level of theory as the author, I was able to obtain the same total electronic energy for the hydrogen atom, I did not observe the same value for the carbon atom, nor did I get the same value for the ethane molecule.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Sure thing! I have elected to do this at the B3LYP/6-31G* level of theory now since I am following a paper who is doing similar calculations at this level. The total electronic energy for the H atom was -0.0500273 Ha, for the C atom -37.776008 Ha, and the sum of electronic energy and ZPE for ethane was -79.679935 Ha. I believe that contains all the necessary ingredients to calculate the heat of formation at 0K. Experimental values for the elements are found in Table 3 if you are looking to do the calculation yourself.

Comment: I cannot do the calculations unfortunately, but others might. I recommend adding all values to your post. You should also include a sample input file. And have you tried another DFA? Maybe B3LYP really does perform crappy on this task. It wouldn't be too surprising.

Comment: @Martin-マーチンI am also noticing that the data the author uses in as an example output does not match the data they are using to do these calculations, which seems quite strange.